# error normal x86_64 while creating appcelerator module for card.io

Tags: ios, xcode7, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, card.io

I am trying to create new appcelerator module using card.io, for that I have added card.io library in Xcode and followed steps accroding to : "https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK ". 
then making build on xcode and creating appcelerator module using python build.py and extracting folder as per appcelerator docs. (All fine)

When I am importing this module in Appcelerator project and trying to run on simulator its showing me error :

```
[ERROR] : ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] : The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] : Ld build/Intermediates/POC.build/Debug-  iphonesimulator/POC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/POC normal x86_64
[ERROR] : (1 failure)
```

Also when I hit command $ ti-64 --global then it's giving me output as " 1.0.0 armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64 " for this module.

I have tried lots of things from google but no luck. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, I'll see if I can have someone look at this. Did you try this existing module for card.io btw? https://github.com/arskinner/Appcelerator-CardIO

Comment: Thanks Fokke, I have resolved this issue. Actually it's because of missing Accelerate and some other framework. I have added these framework and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding All the frameworks that was given on [card.io SDK](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK) and now it's working fine.

Here I am missing Accelerate framework and (libopencv_core.a and libopencv_imgproc.a from CardIO directory).